# Python| Unable to extract the list of names from the text

Tags: python, regex, nlp, spacy, python-re

Executing the below to extract the list of names from the text1. The text1 variable is the merge of the pdf's.
But executing the below code gives just one name out of complete input.
Tried to change patterns but didn't work.

Code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

# load pre-trained model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# initialize matcher with a vocab
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

def extract_name(resume_text):
    nlp_text = nlp(resume_text)
    #print(nlp_text)
    
    # First name and Last name are always Proper Nouns
    pattern = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}]
    
    #matcher.add('NAME', None, [pattern])
    matcher.add('NAME', [pattern], on_match=None)
    
    matches = matcher(nlp_text)
    
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = nlp_text[start:end]
        #print(span)
        return span.text
```

Execution: extract_name(text1)
O/P:  'VIKRAM RATHOD'

Expected O/P: List of all names in the text1

Comment: You using `return` in the for loop so it will only ever return the first instance of matched items ! Replace `return` this by `yield` which will return an `iterable` or append all `span.text` inside a list.

Comment: Also you should initialize the matched inside the function, because calling the `extract_name` function multiple times will add the pattern multiple times to the matched (which could have side effects).

Comment: Detecting the names of people is what NER is for, have you tried using the entity labels / `doc.ents`? Also lots of people don't have names with exactly two parts...

Comment: NER is not working well enough , I am not sure I under stand what is not working ? you are expecting to get all matches and you get only the first one?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have appending in the list span.text to a list , but now i see  two major issues. 1)the names are coming however not only the names but also the o/p is having the unnecessary values (following the pattern ) which arent the names .o/p  ['CHADDA SINGH',
 'SINGH JAIN', 'PROFESSIONAL SUMMARY', 'Data Scientist'] and 2) is  o/p of a name isn't coming proper when its having a middle name.. eg ,  name of a person is CHADDA SINGH JAIN, however its coming twice as CHADDA SINGH and  next as SINGH JAIN.. how to handle these above two issues?

Comment: Modified code:
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
# initialize matcher with a vocab
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
a=[]
def extract_name(resume_text):
    nlp_text = nlp(resume_text)
    # First name and Last name are always Proper Nouns
    pattern = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}]    
    #matcher.add('NAME', None, [pattern])
    matcher.add('NAME', [pattern], on_match=None)    
    matches = matcher(nlp_text)    
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = nlp_text[start:end]
        a.append(span.text)
    return a

Answer (score 0):

For your questions :

Adding the matcher declaration :

```
self._nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg") 
self._matcher = Matcher(self._nlp.vocab)
```

As general best practice remove all punctuation:

```
  table = str.maketrans(string.punctuation,' '*32)   ##Remove punctuation
    sentence = sentence .translate(table).strip()
```

To catch middle name add:

```
pattern = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN',"OP": "*"},{'POS': 'PROPN'}]
```

Now loop over all the matches and add them to a dict

```
   New_list_of_matches={}
   for match_id, start, end in matches:
        string_id = ((self.NlpObj)._nlp.vocab).strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
        span=str((self.NlpObj)._doc[start:end]).split()           
        if string_id in New_list_of_matches:   
            if len(span)>New_list_of_matches[string_id]['lenofSpan']:
                New_list_of_matches[string_id]={'span':span,'lenofSpan':len(span)}
        else:
            New_list_of_matches[string_id]={'span':span,'lenofSpan':len(span)}
```

It is important to keep the length of the span that way you can differ between cases when you find names with 2 words with ones with 3 words(middle name)

Now :

```
for keys,items in  New_list_of_matches.items():
   if keys=='NAME':
          if len(items['span'])==2:
                 Name=items['span'][items['lenofSpan']-2]+' '+items['span'][items['lenofSpan']-1]
          elif len(items['span'])==3:
                Name=items['span'][items['lenofSpan']-3]+items['span'][items['lenofSpan']-2]+' '+items['span'][items['lenofSpan']-1]
```

Comment: Thank you. here where are we defining the self in the code ? also could you pls collate the complete code that you have given..

Comment: My code is OOP you can easily adjust (self.NlpObj)._nlp== nlp in your code